# Passing a string with multiple variables to anrduino using serial port

Tags: arduino, processing

Im trying to pass a string generated using processing to the Arduino serial port but it doesn't seem to work.

Arduino Code:

```
String readString; //main captured String
String MotorChoice;
String AngleRange; 
String FrequencyIN;

int ind1;
int ind2;
int ind3;

int MC;
int AR;
float FIN;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Input command in the form of Motor Choice,Angle Range,Frequency*");
}

void loop() 
{
if (Serial.available())  {
    char c = Serial.read();  
    if (c == '*') {

      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("captured String is : ");
      Serial.println(readString);

      ind1 = readString.indexOf(',');  //finds location of first ,
      MotorChoice = readString.substring(0, ind1);   //captures first data String
      ind2 = readString.indexOf(',', ind1+1 );   //finds location of second ,
      AngleRange = readString.substring(ind1+1, ind2);   //captures second data String
      ind3 = readString.indexOf(',', ind2+1 );
      FrequencyIN = readString.substring(ind2+1);

  //convert sring to int
  MC = MotorChoice.toInt();
  AR = AngleRange.toInt();
  FIN = FrequencyIN.toFloat();

  Serial.print("Motor Selected = ");
  Serial.println(MC);
  Serial.print("Angle Range = ");
  Serial.println(AR);
  Serial.print("Frequency Required = ");
  Serial.println(FIN);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  readString=""; //clears variable for new input
      MotorChoice="";
      AngleRange="";
      FrequencyIN="";
      }

    else
    {     
      readString += c; //makes the string readString
    }
}
}
```

Processing Code:

```
 import processing.serial.*;

 Serial myPort;

 println(Serial.list());
 myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600); 

int M =1;
int A =90;
float F =2.5;


String sM = str(M);
String sA = str(A);
String sF = str(F);
String sb;
String s1;

sb = sM +","+ sA+"," + sF+"*";


s1 = sb;

println(s1);
 myPort.write(s1);
```

The above Arduino code has previously been tried out where an input was fed using the serial monitor in the format of motor,angle,frequency*

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly WHAT "doesn't seem to work"?  Is ANYTHING successfully read from the serial port?

Comment: Are you facing any error? What do mean with "doesn't seem to work"

Comment: Nothing seems to be read from the serial port

Comment: Get something simpler working. Can you create a program that sends a single hard-coded value through?

Comment: Yes that is possible but I'm trying to pass an array converted to a string since I have too many combinations of variables to be passed as bytes which will not fit in the range of 0-255

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your code correctly  you are using the * character as a way of signifying the end of the list. But in your Arduino code you are checking for the * then you are printing the output string. Thus, the rest of your array is long gone by that point. Also, you set a variable at the beginning called `readString` but you never set it to anything. That's why you you're not seeing any output.

First I would start by changing your variable name from `readString` to something else (for the sake of clarity) then use `Serial.readString()` to get that string from the serial port. Then check the last character of that string for the * character.

```
if (Serial.available()) { 
String str = Serial.readString(); // get string
char c = str[strlen(str)-1]; // find *
if (c == '*') {
Serial.print("Output: ");
Serial.println(str);
//The rest of your code
}
```